# What folder are updates kept in so I can sync them?

Tags: updates, sync

I have installed UBUNTU 10.10 at My home PC & The same is installed at My office. Both are installed on separate partition ex4.

At my Home I don't have net connection, I use mobile to connect some time but could not getting much speed.

My office pc have faster net connection through LAN where I can update daily.
My question is what folder should I copy & pest to my home PC to update as at my office?
What are the simple way to keep my both the installation same?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See previous question on this topic [How Can I Install Software Offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

Specifically the reference to the [Keryx Project](http://keryxproject.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptoncd for that http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/ 
According to the site:

APTonCD is a tool with a graphical interface which allows you to create one or more CDs or DVDs (you choose the type of media) with all of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a removable repository that you can use on other computers. APTonCD will also allow you to automatically create media with all of your .deb packages located in one especific repository, so that you can install them into your computers without the need for an internet conection.